# Dictionary Truth Value Testing

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, false-positive, truthiness

```
>>> dict = {}
>>> a=2
>>> if a is not None and dict is None:
...     print("lol")
... else:
...     print(" Print result is a")
... 
   result is a
```

Why does the first `if statement does not run? I am specifying that the`dict`is empty and that`" a"` exists.

Reference: https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing

Comment: `{}` is not `None`, `None` is `None`.

Answer (score 1):

> I am specifying that the dict is empty and that "a" exists.

No, you're not. You're testing whether `a` is not identical to `None` (true) and if `{}` is identical to `None` (false).

What you want is `a and not d`. You almost never want to compare with a boolean, and you certainly never want to do it with `is`.

Comment: Thank you, That cleared up a lot of confusion! :)

Answer (score 1):

Because the dictionary isn't `None`.

There's a difference between a value being falsey, and it satisfying `is None`.

Just test the truthiness directly:

```
if a is not None and not dict:
```

As noted in the comments though, don't name variables the same as existing function names. That's just asking for `'dict' object is not callable` errors in the future.

Comment: Wouldn't use `dict` as var name

Comment: @RafaelC I'm using the same name as the OP for clarity. I'll add a note.